# Ajax jquery autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

I know there's a lot of these kind of post but I wasn't able to find any that suited me. I don't have knowledge of ajax and jquery (in fact I've just started with MVC and ASP.NET) so I need your help in this little thing.

There must be almost everywhere this kind of silly thing, I want to write a city name in a combobox, dropdownlist (or whatever) and using a method that I've already created which returns a list of locations (city, country and state names) that match the entered city. I want it to be dinamyc that's why I thought AJAX would solve this (but any other solution is accepted)

I found this [jQuery autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) but I don't understand where to implement it. I want the combobox to match the bootstrap theme. Could someone tell me if this is an appropiate solution and if so where do I put the ajax content and else? (by where I mean, is it in the view, or controller or where?)

Or you could give mi a hint here is the method I've created for getting the elements from the database:

```
public List<LocationsViewModel> GetHeadquarter(string query)
{
    var context = new HeadquarterContext();
    //var city = context.Cities.Where(p => p.Name == query).Single();
    //var province = context.Provinces.Where(p => p.ProvinceID == city.Province).ToList();
    //foreach(Province prov in province) {

    //}
    var hq =
        from c in context.Cities
        join p in context.Provinces on c.Province equals p.ProvinceID
        join co in context.Countries on p.Country equals co.CountryID
        where c.Name == query
        select new { country = co.Name, province = p.Name, city = c.Name };

    List<LocationsViewModel> listLocation = new List<LocationsViewModel>();

    foreach (var hqe in hq)
    {
        LocationsViewModel loc = new LocationsViewModel();
        loc.City = hqe.city;
        loc.Country = hqe.country;
        loc.Province = hqe.province;
        listLocation.Add(loc);
    }
    return listLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets see if we can get it to work.

View:

> This is added in your view, @Url.Action(Action, Controller) is the Action that is the source for the autocomplete function.

```
<input type="search" class="form-control ui-autocomplete" 
data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Home")" />
```

Controller (Home):

> As you can see the Action Autocomplete was used to search for a product. I have an instance of my database entity called '_db' and have select a table called 'product_data' (**can also use a Stored Procedure**). I'm using LINQ to query the datasource and store it in the variable 'model', so it's querying where the 'term' *StartsWith* what is typed in the textbox, it takes the top 10 and for each one it add label and product. **[{"label":value}]**

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    try
    {
        var model = _db.product_data // your data here
            .Where(p => p.product.StartsWith(term))
            .Take(10)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                // jQuery UI needs the label property to function 
                label = p.product.Trim()
            });

        // Json returns [{"label":value}]
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Settings.ReportException(ex);
        return Json("{'ex':'Exception'}");
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

> This code is when you select a value from the list that is displayed from your search. The 'window.location.href' redirects to a different controller once a value from the autocomplete has been selected.

```
// submits form upon selecting a value
var submitAutocompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
    var $input = $(this); // the HTML element (Textbox)

    // selected value
    $input.val(ui.item.label); // ui.item.label = the label value (product)

    window.location.href = "/Product/Details?id=" + ui.item.label; 
};
```

> The next function sets up the autocomplete API. You declare your options, the above is optional and it comes under **select**, the **source** is required and it points to the *data-attribute* on the HTML element.

```
var createAutocomplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this); // the HTML element (Textbox)

    var options = {
        // selecting the source by finding elements with the 'data-' attribute
        source: $input.attr("data-autocomplete"), // Required
        select: submitAutocompleteForm // Optional
    };

    // apply options
    $input.autocomplete(options);
};

// targets input elements with the 'data-' attributes and each time the input changes
// it calls the 'createAutocomplete' function
$("input[data-autocomplete]").each(createAutocomplete);
```

You'll have to reference the jQueryUI file for autocomplete to work.

Comment: I added the jqueryui reference, but it doesn't work. Keep in mind that I have absolutely no knowledge about js, but I think that it is not well defined (especially this part "/Product/Details?id=" .. I don't know what may I have to change there to reference my work). Besides the autocomplete action result is querying again and the result of the query is already defined in the  GetHeadquarter() method I showed before

Comment: Ok, sorry I have confused you. This is just an example of how to implement it, my action 'Autocomplete' is like your GetHeadquater. I will add comments to the code tomorrow.